# "Error in install.packages : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" in RStudio but not in R. Why?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I execute:

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-2.1")
```

It works in R but not in RStudio. Why?

In RStudio I get:

```
> install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-2.1")
Error in install.packages : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

traceback:

```
> traceback()
3: installed.packages()
2: as.data.frame(installed.packages(), stringsAsFactors = F)
1: (function () 
   {
       uniqueLibPaths <- .rs.uniqueLibraryPaths()
       x <- suppressWarnings(library(lib.loc = uniqueLibPaths))
       x <- x$results[x$results[, 1] != "base", ]
       pkgs.name <- x[, 1]
       pkgs.library <- x[, 2]
       pkgs.desc <- x[, 3]
       pkgs.url <- file.path("help/library", pkgs.name, "html", 
           "00Index.html")
       loaded.pkgs <- .rs.pathPackage()
       pkgs.loaded <- !is.na(match(normalizePath(paste(pkgs.library, 
           pkgs.name, sep = "/")), loaded.pkgs))
       instPkgs <- as.data.frame(installed.packages(), stringsAsFactors = F)
       pkgs.version <- character(length = length(pkgs.name))
       for (i in 1:length(pkgs.name)) {
           pkgs.version[[i]] <- .rs.packageVersion(pkgs.name[[i]], 
               pkgs.library[[i]], instPkgs)
       }
       pkgs.library <- .rs.createAliasedPath(pkgs.library)
       packages = data.frame(name = pkgs.name, library = pkgs.library, 
           version = pkgs.version, desc = pkgs.desc, url = pkgs.url, 
           loaded = pkgs.loaded, check.rows = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
       packages[order(packages$name), ]
   })()
```

I use Windows 10 Enterprise with RStudio 1.0.143 as well as:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness
```

Comment: What does traceback() tell you?

Comment: @Roland Thanks, added

Comment: So, we've nailed it down to installed.packages.

Comment: That error is actually within RStudio-specific code. Do you see the same issue in the current release of RStudio ([v1.0.153](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/))? Do you see the same error if you manually call `.rs.listInstalledPackages()`?